# From projected points on an arbitrary straight line, among them M medium point, find straight line maximizing distance between projected points and M'

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, projective-geometry, projection

I am trying to understand the step going from

1. Having a serial of points projected on an arbitrary straight line
   $C, D, E, F, G \rightarrow C', D', E', F', G'$
   and $M$ the medium point of $C,D,E,F,G$ projected on $M'$

[image]

2. Finding the best straight line that will maximize the sum of the distances between:
   $M'$
   and the other projected points $C', D', E', F', G'$

What is the principle of the action that I am called to do to succeed?
I understand that I will change the $\overrightarrow{AB}$ vector,
but how?

(P.S.: my question hasn't accurate tags: I'm lacking knowledge to classify it)

Comment: It isn't clear however, which quantity is being maximized. For example, one could maximize the sum of the distances of all points in the set from their midpoint $M$, squared.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg You're right! I missed to specify that it's the sum of the distance that I'm trying to optimize by getting it's maximum! I've corrected it in the question.

Comment: The problem is difficult to solve with the sum of distances, but when maximizing the sum of distances squared, it becomes more tractable.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg it's to calculate the first axis of an ellipse of dispersion. My book writes (in French) "_On définit un premier axe qui maximise la somme des distances entre les points projetés sur cette droite, et le centre (moyen ou médian) également projeté sur cette droite_". But I won't be surprised if the author has in mind to calculate $d^2(M', C')$, $d^2(M', D')$ and so on, and eventually take the root square of their summation. But this isn't really said, so I can't assume it.

Comment: This is interesting- when maximizing $d^2$ the problem reduces to finding eigenvectors of the covariance matrix of the dataset, which with a quick look online seems to be exactly the way in which confidence interval ellipses are drawn for 2D data. It's possible that this is what you're looking for, since the problem of drawing those ellipses reduces to extremizing the sum of square distances. Using the $L^1$ norm here seems to draw the equivalent "deviational parallelogram" instead of an ellipse.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the maximum depends on *AB*'s direction but not position, i.e. if we represent *AB* as $y=kx+b$, it only depends on *k* but not *b*.

For example, for `C, D, E, F, G = (14.1, 4.3), (4.2, 4.8), (8.8, 8), (9.7, 0), (14, 3.3)`: if *AB* is parallel to x-axis, we get $|M'C'|+|M'D'|+|M'E'|+|M'F'|+|M'G'|=15.56$ (take x only); if *AB* is parallel to y-axis, we get 9.72 (take y only).

Note that if we project point $(x_0, y_0)$ onto $y=kx$, we get $\left(\dfrac{x_0+ky_0}{1+k^2},\dfrac{k(x_0+ky_0)}{1+k^2}\right)$.

So we can rotate *AB* and find the maximum. Here is the numeric solution by Python:

```
from math import *
from scipy.optimize import *

C, D, E, F, G = (14.1, 4.3), (4.2, 4.8), (8.8, 8), (9.7, 0), (14, 3.3)

def proj(P, k):
    x = (P[0] + k*P[1])/(1 + k**2)
    return x, k*x

def dist(P1, P2):
    return sqrt((P1[0] - P2[0])**2 + (P1[1] - P2[1])**2)

def m(k):
    C1, D1, E1, F1, G1 = proj(C, k), proj(D, k), proj(E, k), proj(F, k), proj(G, k)
    M1 = (C1[0] + D1[0] + E1[0] + F1[0] + G1[0])/5, (C1[1] + D1[1] + E1[1] + F1[1] + G1[1])/5
    return -(dist(M1, C1) + dist(M1, D1) + dist(M1, E1) + dist(M1, F1) + dist(M1, G1))

print(m(0), m(999999))
print(minimize_scalar(m))
```

When *AB* is $y=-0.6339x$, the maximum sum is 17.3334.

---

**Here's it's an edit of me (Marc), the opener of the question:**
I've added to your response my figure with the straight line in orange coming from your calculations:
$y = -0.6339x + 5$
(I've chosen $b=5$ as $b$ value has no effect on the distances of the projected points, like you wrote).

My own line shown roughly (I measured it with a ruler) points summarizing a distance between their projection and $M'$ of
$d(C',M') + d(D',M') + d(E',M') + d(F',M') + d(G',M') = (2.7 + 1.1 + 0.2 + 1.5 + 1.8) \times 2^{*} = 14.6 \text{ units}$
*$^{*}$ my ruler measures centimeters and a square on the paper is 0.5 cm long. So I have to multiply by 2 to return to graph units.*

Your solution gives me:
$d(C'',M'') + d(D'',M'') + d(E'',M'') + d(F'',M'') + d(G'',M'') = (2.2 + 1.5 + 1 + 1.1 + 1.8) \times 2 = 15.2 \text{ units}$

It's possible that the measurements I've done manually here explain the gap of few units between your result and the one I red on my paper for your calculated straight line.
If I had done everything by calculation, and reported the points on a larger figure, I would have had less errors. Thanks for the explanation: I will study it carefully.

[image]

Comment: @MarcLeBihan can you show the values of *C'*, *D'*, ... and *M'*?

Comment: For C'(14.1, 4.3), D'(5.1, 1.6), M'(10.5, 3.2) they are on the paper, but others aren't. E' should be at E'(10.2, 3.2), then F'(8.9, 2.8) and G'(13.7, 4.2).

Comment: $d(C',M')=\sqrt{(14.1-10.5)^2+(4.3-3.2)^2}=3.85$. How do you calculate $d(C',M')$?

Comment: I did a sad measurement mistake: taken manually with a ruler that shows centimeters while units on the paper are half long (each square has 0.5 cm side long). So the two values (7.3 and 7.6) I've reported in the edit I've done on your post had to be corrected by being multiplied by two from these numbers I've corrected them on my part of your answer). But I am unease seeing an ellipse of dispersion starting going that way (if, like I believe I will find, its second axis will be perpendicular to that primary one). I don't feel my C, D, E, F, G points going that way.

Comment: I understand the remaining part that is troubling me. Because I'm in search of the first axis of an ellipsis of dispersion, the straight line calculated will convince me translated to a place between the C, D, E, F, G points. Meaning that the calculation of the $b$ parameter of the $y = ax + b$ straight line is also important, in my case.